# Enlarge image enhance without losing quality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I need to enlarge and enhance its quality for better reading
I tried the following using Pillow to resize the image but I still can't read it well

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('Sample.jpg')
resized_img = img.resize((2450, 3283))
resized_img.save('Output.png')
```

Here's a sample of the image
[image]

Comment: How can you add additional pixel data by just enlarging?

Comment: I have no great idea but I think if the image resized (shrink), the pixels will be clearer, but the problem is that it will not be readable

Comment: Usually you do this with machine learning and a huge amount of training data. In your case the training data should contain arabic text. Otherwise you can not upscale your image, a pixel is a pixel, if you resize/enlarge it, 1 black pixel results in 4 black pixels for example, but doesnt make the printing finer. Check [github projects](https://github.com/search?q=image+upscale&type=Repositories) or [waifu2k](https://github.com/AaronFeng753/Waifu2x-Extension-GUI). [Here are attempts with waifu2k](https://imgur.com/a/KBMytlQ), could not make the numbers readable, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need that for a simple project. Just remove the colored background, turn the text to black pixels with some threshold (something to enhance reading it)